# My form ignores Required attributes from model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, validation, model

I'm having troubles with my form validation. For some reason the form ignores any [Required] attribute I have in my model.

**Model:** (Stripped down for easy read)

```
public class NotEmployeesModel
{
    public NotEmployeesModel()
    {
        DetailModel = new NotEmployeesDetailModel();
    }
    public NotEmployeesDetailModel DetailModel { get; set; }
}

public class NotEmployeesDetailModel
{
    public NotEmployeesDetailModel()
    {

    }

    public NotEmployeesDocumentModel DocumentModel { get; set; }
}

public class NotEmployeesDocumentModel
{
    public NotEmployeesDocumentModel()
    {

    }

   public NotEmployeeDocumentInputModel DocumentInput { get; set; }

    public class NotEmployeeDocumentInputModel
    {
        public NotEmployeeDocumentInputModel()
        {

        }

        public NotEmployeeDocumentInputModel(int notEmployeeId)
        {
            NotEmployeeId = notEmployeeId;
        }

        public int NotEmployeeId { get; set; }
        public int SelectedDocumentType { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorMessages), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Star")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorMessages), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Star")]
        public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
    }
}
```

For each view or partial I have a separate model class.

**Form:**

```
@model NotEmployeesDocumentModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddNotEmployeeDocument", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form-add-document", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.DocumentInput.NotEmployeeId)
<table class="table-output">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.Label("Sort", Labels.Sort)</td>
            <td>@Html.Label("Description", Labels.Description)</td>
            <td>@Html.Label("Type", Labels.Type)</td>
            <td class="text-align-right"></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <i class="fa fa-plus-square cursor-pointer add-document"></i>
                    <input type="file" id="DocumentInput_File" name="DocumentInput.File" required="required" />
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.DocumentInput.File)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.DocumentInput.Description, new { @class = "width300px hardware-setup-input", placeholder = "Vul hier een omschrijving in..." })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.DocumentInput.Description)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.DocumentInput.SelectedDocumentType, Model.DocumentTypes, "--- Maak een keuze ---")
                </td>
                <td class="text-align-right">
                    <span id="btn-add-document" class="button-org">@Labels.Save</span>
                </td>
            </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
}
```

Structure of my page: View / Partial / Partial (Here is my form)

**JS:**

```
$("#btn-add-document").on("click", function () {
            var frm = $("#form-add-document");
            if (frm.valid()) {
                frm.ajaxSubmit({
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (responseText) {
                        $("#document-container").html(responseText);
                        $("#DocumentInput_Description").text("");
                        $("#DocumentInput_SelectedDocumentType").val("");
                        loadDocumentPartial();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

I'm using jQuery Form plugin from malsup to submit my form through ajax.

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddNotEmployeeDocument(NotEmployeesDocumentModel input)
{
    // do some code

}
```

As you can see in the parameters of my ActionResult I can't put NotEmployeesDocumentInputModel like I always do but I'm forced to use the parent class.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. This is the first time I encounter such problem.

Comment: First thing to check: are the various `data-` attributes being generated in the HTML? If they are not you have a problem in the HTML generation; if they are you have a problem with running the validation. Also: have you enabled unobtrusive JS validation?

Comment: @Richard Yes, the attributes are generated and JS validation is enabled. This is not my first form in the application. Others work perfectly.

Comment: Your form is based on type of `NotEmployeeDocumentInputModel` so the parameter in your method need to be that, not `NotEmployeesDocumentModel ` other wise nothing will be bound (all the properties of `input` will be their defaults

Comment: No thats not true. The property NotEmployeeDocumentInput inside NotEmployeeDocumentModel is not empty. That works!

Comment: It does not  work when I put NotEmployeeDocumentInputModel like you say. Then nothing is bound but I have no clue  why?

Comment: Unless you passing a prefix as additional view data when you generate your partial, then no it wont

Comment: I am not sure what you mean but thats not my question even though I would like to find a solution for that aswell.

Comment: Why on earth do you have those nested classes? `NotEmployeesDocumentModel` does not even contain a property named  `DocumentInput` (at least you have not shown it)

Comment: Sorry, it does have the property. I think I stripped too much. Will edit it. I want to update different pieces of the page separately, so I use partials and for each partial a Model. When I return the partial I only have to reload the fields used for the partial.